# CSS vertical-align Bottom for Text

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I am trying myself a bit on Website layout. 
So I have started designing a page.

I want my start page to be divided with a horizontal division line. 
So far, so good. 
Now each of the two fields needs some text and I want the text to have a `vertical align: bottom`.

My research on the internet got me the result that there is no real possibility to do like that for `<div>` tags. But there is one for a table cell.

My HTML code looks like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TITLE</title>
<link href="firstPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<section class="half">
  <div class="titletext">
    TEXT 
    <br>
    TEXT
  </div>
</section>

<section class="half">
  <div class="titletext">
    TEXT
    <br>
    TEXT
  </div>
</section>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS class looks like that:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'corbertregular', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
}
header {
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
}
main {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background: green;
}
.half {
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.half:first-child {
    background: #F3A008;

}
.half:last-child {
    background: #950049;
}

.titletext{
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}
```

I have found that site as a useful solution, 
but it does not work for me....

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

What am I doing for a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Change this class in your CSS:

```css
.titletext{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;        
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```